# Issues with Carrierwave in Rails 3.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I'm trying to attach a file "attachment" to my upload model.  The attachment field in my db after creation is nil, and links link @upload.attachment.url just redirect to a parent object.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong?  I haven't used Carrierwave before.

```
# Model
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader
end
```

Went with the basics for for the attachment field

```
# Form
= form_for @upload, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  %br
  = f.file_field :attachment
```

And more basics with the controller:

```
def create
  @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])
  @upload.attachment = params[:file]
  if @upload.save
    redirect_to @upload
  end
end
```

I'm not getting any errors in my console, but the :attachment string on the student model is always nil.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why u have added the line

> @upload.attachment = params[:file]

remove it. it will work. attachment string is null because there is not params file in the form.